# Ordenar los valores de un diccionario en base a una propiedad

Tags: python

Quisiera obtener una lista de tuplas o un diccionario donde el resultado sea el siguiente diccionario ordenado por el número atómico de cada elemento.

```py
elementos = {'Fe':{'Nombre': 'Hierro', 'No. Atomico': 26, 'Grupo': 8},
              'O':{'Nombre': 'Oxigeno', 'No. Atomico': 8, 'Grupo': 16},
              'H':{'Nombre': 'Hidrogeno', 'No. Atomico': 1, 'Grupo': 1},
              'C':{'Nombre': 'Carbono', 'No. Atomico': 6, 'Grupo': 14},
              'P':{'Nombre': 'Fosforo', 'No. Atomico': 15, 'Grupo': 15}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python 3.6+**

Podrías utilizar `sorted` y `lambda`

```py
sortedElementos = sorted(elementos.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['No. Atomico'])

print(sortedElementos)
```

Obtendrás una lista de tuples en dónde el primer elemento es el símbolo del elemento químico y el segundo es el conjunto de atributos de ese elemento químico. La lista estará ordenada en base al número atómico.

```py
[('H', {'Nombre': 'Hidrogeno', 'No. Atomico': 1, 'Grupo': 1}), 
('C', {'Nombre': 'Carbono', 'No. Atomico': 6, 'Grupo': 14}), 
('O', {'Nombre': 'Oxigeno', 'No. Atomico': 8, 'Grupo': 16}), 
('P', {'Nombre': 'Fosforo', 'No. Atomico': 15, 'Grupo': 15}), 
('Fe', {'Nombre': 'Hierro', 'No. Atomico': 26, 'Grupo': 8})]
```

Si requieres un diccionario, tendrías que mapear la lista de tuples a un diccionario:

```py
diccionarioSorted = {key: info for key, info in sortedElementos}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los diccionarios son elementos intrínsecamente no ordenados, para ordenar sus elementos supongo que quieras llevarlo a una lista, con el siguiente pedazo de código deberías poder deducir lo que quieres hacer :).

Una primera versión con una lista de tuplas:

```py
sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['No. Atomico'])
```

Y una segunda versión dando como resultado un diccionario de vuelta.

```py
{k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['No. Atomico'])}
```